# Best strategy to add elements dynamically to an activity

Tags: android, performance

I'm trying to make an activity able to capture up to 4 images for sending them to our server.
*I know how to capture the image and to add them to the activity*, this already works, in a **non efficient** nor **elegant** way, and I would like to improve that.

Right now, I have `Button` with an `onClick` method that attaches an image to an empty `ImageView`, and and keeps track of how many images have been attached, because I can delete an image in order to pick a new one.

I'm wondering the best strategy, code-wise for future changes.

Options that I have considered but I have not (yet) implemented:

- `Button` adds the image to a `GridView` so I can add and remove images from it's adapter instead.
- The `ImageView` can attach and remove image from itself by `onClick` and therefore remove the `Button`

Any suggestions, ideas, strategies, thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

### EDIT 1: my first approach to improve the code

I've implemented a `GridView` with a custom adapter (`GridImageAdapter`)

```
public class GridImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    private int img_height;
    public GridImagesAdapter(Context context, List<Bitmap> imagenes){
        this.imagenes = imagenes;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        img_height = (int) (metrics.density * Constants.ONE_ROW_IMG_HEIGHT);
    }
    /*
     * other common methods
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(row == null){
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_img_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_add_in_grid);
            holder.image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, img_height));
            holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(getItem(position));
        row.setTag(holder);
        return row;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

So I can populate my `GridView` in the activity like:

```
private void populateGridView(){
    Bitmap a;
    a = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image);
    images.add(a);
    images.add(a);
    images.add(a);
    images.add(a);
    GridImagesAdapter adapter = new GridImagesAdapter(this, images);
    mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new GetImage());
}
```

where `new GetImage()` is an `OnItemClickListener` who takes care of the image capture itself, and replaces one of the `R.drawable.no_image` Bitmap 
(no relevant code in there, just showing a `Dialog` to the user in order to choose from camera or gallery and start such `Activity`, and then in the `onActivityResult` method where I have a `Bitmap` to work with is where I handle the adapter change)

---

My question is more about **the strategy** chosen here than the actual code itself.
Drawbacks? Any more elegant or proper way to achieve the same result?

Everything is welcome, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Have u create a gridview and set up the adapter class?

Because I have implemented a similar case. Items are added to listview dynamically (by user input), and there is a button in each row that deletes that particular row (also from the database).

If u have, Let me know from where shall we begin.

Comment: Right now, I've implemented a mix of both options. I have a GridView, initialized with 4 empty images, where every image (a "no image" image) has an `OnClick` method which attaches a new image to it

Comment: I've updated my question so it shows how my actual code looks like

Comment: to improve performance of listview, dont use ArrayList in adapter class. instead create a new class for your object and set "Getters and Setters" there. This was mentioned in the google's i/o about listview. they have also prefereed base adapter over array adapter.

Comment: then u can use libraries like Picasso or Universal Image Loader to improve bitmap downloading, loading and automatic cache management

Comment: Thanks Hirak, can you provide me any link or info about that particular I/O talk where they talked about that? I would like to check it out.

Comment: sure. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQyCkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&ei=uAlZVLLiFpKwuASoxoGIAg&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=A_dNaebG4sL_VtihYbb6CA&bvm=bv.78677474,d.c2E

Comment: sure https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. look this. this 1 hour is really worth spending. infact u should also check out google i/o videos on design principles and all that

Answer (score 0):

Your general idea is more or less correct. You mentioned `GetImage` is irrelevant, but it absolutely isn't. From I understood, you are changing the view directly in there. Instead you should manipulate the adapter, changing the data it's holding, and then call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()). The adapter will take care of notifying the gridview that the data changed and the view will be updated. I would probably use an ArrayAdapter instead of a BaseAdapter as well.

Comment: Yes João, indeed the `GetImage` is relevant to the general goal, but not to my question. 
I mean, `getImage` in fact is just presenting a `Dialog` to the user in order to choose from camera or gallery and starting such `Activity`, and then on the `onActivityResult` method where I have a `Bitmap` to work with is where I handle the adapter change as you mentioned.